# Swagger-UI: insert HTML content after "Execute"

Tags: swagger-ui

I have the following customized Swagger-UI layout consisting of two columns.
In the left pane the SwaggerUI and in the right pane a empty <div> container

[image: Picture]

The response I get on 'Execute' contains some HTML:

```
<div id="some guid">
<script> ... code to fill that div </script>
```

How can I put this content into the right pane ?

I tried with a responseInterceptor but the script gets not executed.
Is there any callback or event I can use ?

Thanks in advance

Nandi

Comment: I suggest asking this in the [Swagger UI repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/new/choose) so that you can get an answer directly from the UI devs.

Comment: It seems that I can only submit issues there. Is there a possibility to ask questions ?

Comment: Yes, choose the "Support" option.